# recursion using yield from

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a divide&conquer function that uses 'yield / yield from' for recursion.

```
def divide_and_conquer(number1, number2):
    print(f'[{number1}, {number2}]')
    if number1 != number2:
        mid = (number1 + number2) // 2
        yield from divide_and_conquer(number1, mid)
        yield from divide_and_conquer(mid+1, number2)

divide_and_conquer(0, 10)
```

As far as I know, it should've worked in this way. The function works when I remove yield from but I'm trying to get use of it.

When I remove yield from, I get the expected result as I said:

```
[0, 10]
[0, 5]
[0, 2]
[0, 1]
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 5]
[3, 4]
[3, 3]
[4, 4]
[5, 5]
[6, 10]
[6, 8]
[6, 7]
[6, 6]
[7, 7]
[8, 8]
[9, 10]
[9, 9]
[10, 10]
```

Comment: Please include in your question: what you expected to happen and what happened (e.g. a traceback or wrong result)

Comment: Ah, I see. When you call `divide_and_conquer(0, 10)`, you are just creating a generator. Try `print(divide_and_conquer(0, 10))` to see what I mean. You are supposed to iterate through the results in order for something ti happen, so: `for result in divide_and_conquer(0, 10): print(result)` - of course, it does not generate any result, it just prints, which is wrong

Comment: I get what your point is, but I'm curious about that can't I just call the function and make it all happen?

Comment: I suggest you should read about generators and `yield` on [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and elsewhere. The fact that nothing happens is the feature of generator functions. Why are you using `yield` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a strange pattern. You are effectively creating a generator, but never actually `yield`ing anything. Your `print` instead of `yield` is not right. You probably want to return (actually `yield`) the value you are now printing, so just yield them instead of printing them.

```
def divide_and_conquer(number1, number2):
    yield [number1, number2]
    if number1 != number2:
        mid = (number1 + number2) // 2
        yield from divide_and_conquer(number1, mid)
        yield from divide_and_conquer(mid+1, number2)

for i in divide_and_conquer(0, 10):
  print(i)
```

^ That is how I think your code should be rewritten. However, the core thing why your code does not work is because you think you are calling a function that would just recursively execute. But you are setting up a generator, which does not iterate on itself. To give you an idea, if you trigger the generator's iterations, your code would still work - **but that's not how you should do it**. See my code above.

**This works but should be avoided.**

```
def divide_and_conquer(number1, number2):
    print([number1, number2])
    if number1 != number2:
        mid = (number1 + number2) // 2
        yield from divide_and_conquer(number1, mid)
        yield from divide_and_conquer(mid+1, number2)

for _ in divide_and_conquer(0, 10):
  pass
```

If you just want to run a function without a generator, you can modify your code as follows. Now your function is not a generator anymore. Note that you don't "return" any values so you can't use the created values outside the function.

```
def divide_and_conquer(number1, number2):
    print([number1, number2])
    if number1 != number2:
        mid = (number1 + number2) // 2
        divide_and_conquer(number1, mid)
        divide_and_conquer(mid+1, number2)

divide_and_conquer(0, 10)
```

Comment: I get what is wrong but can't I just call the function to make this all happen? I mean the recursion with just the call, not with for loop.

Comment: @staydin `print(*divide_and_conquer(0, 10), sep='\n')`

Comment: `list(divide_and_conquer(0, 10))` would also do the the same thing.

Comment: @AChampion Definitely true, but it doesn't feel right because you expect something to be 'returned', or 'listed' when in fact you are not listing anything. You are just exhausting the generator (which returns nothing). So basically, you're just creating an empty list.